# How to solve the irrecognizable characters while curl this page

Tags: php, curl

My code is here, the problem is different with my other question, here I meet the problem is after I successfully curl down the page, but all I see the characters are irrecognizable, eg. "��Ƶ�̳̣�2012�棩", how to make them appear normally?

```
$cookie_file = tempnam('./temp','cookie');
$login_url = 'http://bbs.php100.com/login.php';
$post_fields = 'cktime=3600&step=2&pwuser=username&pwpwd=password';

$ch = curl_init($login_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie_file);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_fields);
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$url = 'http://bbs.php100.com/index.php';//or specific page
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie_file);
$contents = curl_exec($ch);

//preg_match("",$contents,$arr);
//echo $arr[1];

curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: How do you "see" this characters? Do you echo them to command line or show on page? How do you modify text before outputing?

Comment: These are my whole code, I see this characters in web browser(firefox).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to save the contents of the page to variable and convert encoding.

```
$url = 'http://bbs.php100.com/index.php';//or specific page
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
// Note "1"! It is needed for curl_exec() to return contents of the page
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie_file);
$contents = curl_exec($ch);
$contents = iconv('gbk','utf8',$contents);
echo $contents;
```

If you are using not `UTF-8` encoding, set second parameter of `iconv` according to your needs.